# What exactly does the "Delete this Epic" button do?

Tags: zenhub

I have an epic in Zenhub and I want it to be a regular issue. I removed all the issues from the epic, and I see a button labeled "Delete this Epic", but what happens when I press it? I don't want the entire issue to be deleted -- I want to keep thie issue with all its comments and history.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing "Delete this Epic" does *not* delete the issue. You will be asked "Are you sure you want to convert the epic X to an issue?", and if you continue, it will remove the Epic label and the list of sub-issues, but the issue remains (with the same issue number), and all the comments and history will remain intact.